# firebase rewrites sub-domains

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

at first I have to paths one for API ans second for regular website,
so I want separate the API as subdomain like that

```
    "rewrites":[
  {
    "source":"domain.com/**",
    "destination":"/index.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "api.domain.com/**",
    "function": "app"
  }
]
```

I have tried many ways but all failed , How can I do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is possible to have multiple subdomains in a single Firebase Hosting project, it is not configured through rewrites in `firebase.json`. You'll instead need to set up the subdomains in the Firebase console, and then configure them through the Firebase CLI. For a full walkthrough of the steps, have a look at the [documentation for multi-site setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites).

Comment: hi, frank thanks for your help , but i don't have multiple sites all i need to association a subdomain to specific your like `domain/api`

Comment: Subdomains are treated the same as multiple sites.